# Get Plain HTML from HTTP Requests

Tags: groovy, httprequest, grails-2.0, httpbuilder

I'm working on a grails app and for several hours already have been trying to get html code from a request. What I want to do is to get plain html (like in a webPage source, with all tags and stuff), so that i can work on that.

I have already managed to get it for my get requests with this code:

```
url = ("http://google.com").toURL().getText())
```

It works just fine, but I also need to be able to make post requests.

I've tried with httpBuilder, but the response I'm getting looks like well formated text (with white spaces and stuff), but that hasn't got any html tags, and I need them. Code I'm using looks like this:

```
def url = "http://urlToRemoteServer.com/"
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url);


http.post( path: 'pathToMyApp',
        requestContentType: "text/xml" ) { resp, reader ->

            println "Tweet response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
            assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
            System.out << reader
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get that html code? I'm working on groovy, but Java solution will be just as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the post map to include the `contentType` to force plain-text parsing (and, I believe change to `Accepts` header) as below:

```
http.post( path: 'pathToMyApp',
           requestContentType: "text/xml",
           contentType: "text/xml") { resp, reader ->
```

Alternatively, you can change parser for this and future requests by adding a [`ParserRegistry`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/ParserRegistry.html) remap after the constructor:

```
http.parser.'text/html' = http.parser.'text/plain'
```

You can also add a call to [`setContentType()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.html#setContentType%28java.lang.Object%29), after your constructor call for `HTTPBuilder`:

```
//...
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url);  //existing code
http.contentType = ContentType.TEXT //new addition
http.post( path: 'pathToMyApp', //existing code
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do it:

```
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT 
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC       

def url = "http://urlToRemoteServer.com/"

def http = new HTTPBuilder(url);

http.request( Method.POST, TEXT) { resp, reader ->

    println "Tweet response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
    assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
    println reader.text
}
```

Loosely based on the information contained at http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/contentTypes.html

Comment: i think you might need to change the closure in this case.  The 2-arg version doesn't work with `request()`, at least in 0.6  version.  Note that reqest content-type is also altered by this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static post(String url, String data, def contentType = ContentType.XML) {
    def client = new HTTPBuilder(url)
    def xml = null
    client.request(groovyx.net.http.Method.POST) {
        contentType = contentType
        requestContentType = contentType  
        body = data
        response.success = { resp, raw ->
            println "Success response: ${resp.statusLine} ->\n${raw.text}"
            xml = [status: resp.statusLine, response:raw]
        }
        response.failure = { resp, raw ->
            println "Error response: ${resp.statusLine} ->\n${raw.text}"
            xml = [status: resp.statusLine, response:raw]
        }      
    } 
    return xml
}
```